# Как точечно взять необходимые мне данные из byte[] в необходимые данные?

Tags: c#

В общем, у меня есть `byte[]`.
Известнно, что с оффсета 2 лежит 7 битов, которые мне нужны, которые обозначают некоторое кол-во (пусть N).

С оффсета 9 лежат другие данные величиной 7 битов и их я должен считать N раз.

Как я могу эту сделать?
Обязательно ли юзать стримы или я могу через AsSpan нарезать необходимые куски данные?

Comment: `var slice1 = byteArray[2..8]` `var slice2 = byteArray[9..15]` ?

Comment: оффсета 2 чего? бит, байт, килобайт? Что такое "считать N раз"? Зачем вообще более одного раза читать одно и то же? вы сами читали свой вопрос? ) И не "битов", а "бит".

Comment: @iiKuzmychov А почему 2..8, а не 2..7?

Comment: @iluxa1810 потому что 2 и 8 это индексы, а не индекс и длина